# JavaScript focus() function doesn't focus textarea on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Focus issue</title>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
  var text = document.getElementById('text')
  window.onload = function() {
    text.focus()
  }
  window.onhashchange = function() {
    text.focus()
  }
}//]]>  
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea id="text"></textarea>
  <p><a href="#focus">Click to focus</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a JSFiddle demo of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/DvU63/

Why doesn't the focus go on the textarea box when the page loads? On clicking the link, the focus does go on the textarea box, but I also want the focus to go to the textarea box on page load. Why doesn't it happen?

Note: I am aware of the HTML5 autofocus attribute for textarea. But this question is about why the above JavaScript code does not do what I intend to do.

Comment: I think it does work, http://jsfiddle.net/DvU63/1/

Comment: @Sergio Do you have an explanation about why adding an input text field resolves the issue?

Comment: @Sergio My question is not specific to jsfiddle. Copy paste my code in this question and paste it to a file, say, foo.html and open it with Firefox and the same issue occurs.

Comment: Yes, I understood that after @nnnnnn called my attention. You have a scope problem and I think his explanation is the answer to your question (and should be the accepted answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing the `.focus()` statement from inside an `onload` handler that is itself defined inside an `onload` handler. This inner `onload` will not be called because by the time you define it the `onload` event will have occurred. Try this:

```
window.onload=function(){
  var text = document.getElementById('text')
  text.focus()

  window.onhashchange = function() {
    text.focus()
  }
}
```

Your demo, updated: http://jsfiddle.net/DvU63/2/

Answer (score 1):

do this

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    window.onload=function(){
    var text = document.getElementById('text')

    text.focus();

    window.onhashchange = function() {
        text.focus();
    }
  }
</script>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DvU63/3/)